# How to make camera continuously move along the circle path?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, camera, constraints, parent

In my scene I have a circle (curve) and a camera, attached to it via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > follow path.

How can I make the camera continue moving along the circle, after the first loop ends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't attach camera to curve. Unparent  it and use the follow path constraint on the camera. Set the camera coordinates to 0,0,0 (this should put the camera on the path, if not you can do it manually. Check follow curve, then set the camera rotation. This should work.

here is what mine looks like:

[image]

Comment: No problem glad I could be of assistance. I should point out that there are many ways of going about the same problem but this solution seemed the most appropriate to your question.